# Disable search button if there's no input and hide search table if the page loads first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am creating a JSP page which has few fields for searching.
I am facing 2 issues.

1) The search button should be disabled until at least one field is not empty. The form has mixed type of fields(few text boxes, drop downs, etc). I have tried few things but the button is not disabling.

2) Second issue is the search result is being displayed in the same page. I am displaying the search result in a table inside a div. I am trying to hide this table until the user doesn't click on search. I have tried doing this by setting a flag in my controller but it's not working.

I have tried using javascript and JQuery for these but for no avail. Pls help!!

#### Edit 1:

I have used something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
             $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');  
             $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){  
                    if($(this).val != ''){  
                       $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    }  
             });  
         });
```

But when I'm using this, the drop downs are not being populated with model object.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#yourFormId > *').filter(':input[value!=""]').length` will return the number of form fields that are not empty.

Im not sure what you want to do with the table though, seems like you should just be able to set `display:none` on the table and use the jQuery css function to change it when the user clicks.

Posting a code sample would help :)